# XNA Too many textures loaded in memory

Tags: memory, xna, loading, textures

I am working on a level editor for a graphics engine. Recently, as one project expanded I have been experiencing memory issues. In particular, the level is quite big and around 300 textures of varying size need to be loaded. A few textures are quite big like 2048x2048, others are smaller like 256x256 or 512x512. Anyway, the editor consumes 1.3gb of memory for this level and some textures can't be loaded as it throws out of memory exceptions. So what solutions do I have here?

Right now the only solution I can think of is to divide the level into smaller parts and load the textures on demand, depending on the visible area. But I believe this would slow down the performance big time when navigating in the scene. Any thoughts? There should be some standard approach for level editors on that matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have two options

1. Switch to a tile-based approach. If you're using tiles, that means you can re-use the same texture over and over which saves a lot of memory.
2. Switch to on-demand as you described.

I'm thinking that if your art direction doesn't really mesh with the tile-based approach, so you will want to start thinking about approach #2.  A few things to think about

- It doesn't necessarily have to be slow, as long as your "active" regions are big enough so that you don't thrash the disk by loading too often you should be fine.
- Measure measure measure, you probably have to get a better grip on what your memory budget is, and design your levels around that rather than designing until you hit a wall. :-)
- Maintain separate content managers, remember that you can't unload an individual piece of content loaded through contentmanager, so keep a list of managers that you can swap out as you move around.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for answering. Now, although I'm not familiar with the tile based approach, one texture can be used by multiple objects. It's not loaded multiple times in the memory for each object that uses it. I'd like to note that textures are saved in a Dictionary<string, Texture2D>. I don't use a content manager, I load the textures with Texture2D.FromFile. I may try that on demand approach. Will the use of a content manager save any memory? I guess not, so I should stick with the already implemented method. P.S I'm only responsible for the tools, the "measurements" are done by others :)

Comment: Oh, I see ... well, the content manager is really only for the runtime code, for textures run through the content pipeline. I assumed you meant that you were running out of memory when you try to run the game. But the mechanism you describe is the same concept ... store references to the texture, and load/unload as you move around. But remember to do so in batches slightly larger than the screen, so that you don't have to constantly load/reload if the user makes small movements.

Comment: Look at how google/bing maps loads textures as you move around the map ... you will want to emulate this

Comment: Yeah, I guess this should be my goal, to emulate a google maps like behavior. The out of memory exceptions are thrown while the level is loading and the memory consumption is growing. Anyway, I will try the on demand method as it seems to be the only solution. Thanks :)

Comment: I do have a question though. If the user zooms out and the whole scene is visible, then all textures will be loaded and that would throw the exceptions again :(

Comment: Yes, that is unfortunately a concern, but there may be a solution if you really want to solve that problem :-) if the user zooms out past a certain point, you could render the current view into a single texture rendertarget and then unload all the individual images ... then load all the surrounding areas as the user zooms out and render into an image. When they're fully zoomed out, all they're looking at is really a composited image of multiple pre-rendered textures. This is similar to the user of impostors to render huge 3d scenes

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to use with different quality of textures, if you're far away use the 64x64 texture, then when you get closer keep swaping it out to 128x128, 256x256, 512x512, etc...  Also reconsider using textures of 2056x2056, since its better to have 4 1024x1024 textures :).

(note: generating mip-maps partially does this, but doesn't free memory on your computer)

Edit: also try to turn on DXT5 texture compression, that might save a lot of memory!

Comment: Basically it turned out that using DXT5 compression was the solution instead of on demand loading at least until levels grow even larger. The memory consumption dropped from 1.3gb to 300-400mb. Quite a performance boost! As for the texture sizes, there are some textures that need to be large, like texture atlases or textures used in regular animations. Although I can change the code to support animations from multiple sources, I can't demand the engine programmer to do the same in the engine ;) (I'm developing an editor for the engine)